# Installing custom R package in the WRDS cloud

Tags: r, installation, package, cloud, wrds

I tried to install custom R package 'sf' in the WRDS cloud via interactive R session, but failed. The instruction from WRDS is:

https://wrds-www.wharton.upenn.edu/pages/support/programming-wrds/programming-r/installing-r-packages/

I followed the instructions and the package 'sf_0.9-6.tar.gz' is already in the '~/lib/R' directory:

[image: List of files in the directory]

When i tried to install the package in the interactive R session, i typed in the code :

```
install.packages("~/sf_0.9-6.tar.gz", lib = "~/lib/R")
```

I got the following error: [image: error description]

I don't understand why it is an invalid package, even though i've downloaded the package directly from CRAN. Besides, the package should work on the R 3.6.2.

Could anyone help? I would highly appreciated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar issue with installation of another user-written package (from CRAN) on R 4.0.5 but, I guess, the root cause of the issue is the same which is that `install.packages` can not find the package TAR file in the directory `/home/<institutionName>/<userName>` (note: this is what the ~ stands for).

Could you try replacing your code:

```
install.packages("~/sf_0.9-6.tar.gz", lib = "~/lib/R")
```

with

```
install.packages("~/lib/R/sf_0.9-6.tar.gz", lib = "~/lib/R")
```

Expanding the path of the package to the newly created R sub-folder within the lib folder worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In the past months I found another solution to get around with this package, but thanks anyway!